# order of dimensions when creating multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, multidimensional-array

`new T[7]` creates an array of 7 `T`s. If we replace `T` with `int[5]`, we get `new int[5][7]` which should create an array of 7 arrays of 5 integers. However, it creates an array of 5 arrays of 7 integers instead. Is there any good reason for this? Wouldn't it make more sense if it was the other way around?

Comment: All C-like languages use [row-major ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). Fortran uses column major. Think of it as *most significant dimension first*.

Comment: I think the question is perfectly appropriate, a frequent source of confusion. It is one of the (many) reasons for me to shun 'bare' multidimensional arrays in C++

Comment: When you do a lookup, the indices go in the same order as the dimensions, which I think makes more sense than the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think of it as dimensions:

```
   height width depth
int[5]    [7]   [8]
```

Or

```
   rows  cols
int[5]   [7]
```

That's why it makes sense for it to be 5 arrays of 7 ints to me. There is a kind of natural order.

I think your example also makes sense and is very logical. So I guess it's just a matter of opinion :P

Answer (score -1):

`int ints [][] = new int [5][7];` can be written as `int [] ints [] = new int [5][7];` maybe this will tell you that it does make sense that those are 5 arrays of 7 integers. ;)

Comment: Is that even true? Also, I don't see how it helps

Comment: This is a funny answer, +1 from me.